# How to Validate JSON objects without using any external libraries

Tags: json, node.js

I want to validate a JSON object without the help of any libraries in nodejs.

Comment: Please define what do you mean by `validate` and post a sample json

Comment: And what did you find so far and why it doesn't fit your needs?

Comment: I just want to know if the JSON object is valid without errors. there are a lot of libraries which does the job I want to do it without using them.

Comment: i just want to check if the json objcet passed is without errors and in proper syntax.

Comment: Just use [JSON.prase](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse). It will throw error if invalid json. Look at the link provided by @ChrisR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just by parsing it, using `JSON.parse` function:

```
function isValidJSON(text){
    try{
        JSON.parse(text);
        return true;
    }
    catch (error){
        return false;
    }
}


console.log(isValidJSON("hello")); // false
console.log(isValidJSON("{}")); // true
```